# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

В каком варианте знаки препинания расставлены верно? И каким правилом надо руководствоваться?
(Разные интернет-сайты выдали такие разные результаты.)

1. Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям, — они начало поступков.
2. Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям, они — начало поступков.
3. Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям — они начало поступков.

Answer (score 1):

1) Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям, - они начало поступков.

Это двойной знак "запятая-тире", здесь он вряд ли уместен.

2) Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям, они - начало поступков.

БСП, запятая ставится, если второе предложение продолжает тему первого. Тире авторское, оно позволяет выделить местоимение и сделать паузу.

3) Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям - (так как) они начало поступков.

БСП, тире обозначает причинно-следственные отношения, заменяет классическое двоеточие (причина на втором месте). Такое тире можно назвать присоединительным.

Таким образом, верны предложения 2 и 3, они имеют разную структуру и интонацию, разное логическое выделение слов.

Answer (score 0):

Будьте внимательны к своим мыслям: они начало поступков.
Бессоюзное сложное предложение. Второе - поясняет первое.

Comment: А все приведенные предложения неверны?